# Render vue js build into Node js and Hapi js project

Tags: node.js, vue.js, handlebars.js, hapi.js, vision

I built a frontend website in vue js, and now i am trying to program 
the backend, in nodejs and hapijs. 
And I tried to define handlebars view engine for load the vue build files. 
And I want to know how can I render a vue project in the server with hapi js, 
Beacuse now, I tried to render the built index of vuejs, and its loaded it without the js, and css files, and I didnt understand how to load the file with all the static content.

That what I tried:

```
await server.register([require('hapi-auth-basic'), require('vision')]);

server.views({
  engines: {
    html: require('handlebars')
  },
  path: './views',
  layout: true
})



server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/',
  handler: (request, h) => {
    console.log(request.auth.credentials);
    return h.view('index');
  }
});
```

So, it shows me the page title, but all other files get a forbbiden response.

Structure: 
server
 -> views
  -> index.html
  static
   -> css/js/img/fonts...

Thank for help!

Comment: Would [this](https://github.com/Belar/hapi-vue) help?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you're running into is that you're missing the "relativeTo" property on your `server.views({ ... })` registration, plus you need to setup the server to serve static files [as outlined in the documentation here](https://hapijs.com/tutorials/serving-files). It's worth noting that while hapi can serve out static files just fine, it's not a great idea to let it do it in production. I personally prefer creating an nginx or apache rule to read the files from the assets directory on match as it's much more performant.